# Other expressions for "Receive a phone call"?

Tags: phrase-request

I use "receive a phone call from someone", but always have thought other simple phrases instead of that. What is it ?

Comment: You could use something like 'got a call from someone'.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "receive a phone call from someone" is a bit wordy, although the most formal and correct.

Using the verb call is common to contextually refer to calling on the phone in less formal settings.

> Someone called.
>
> They called earlier.

Comment: Yes it’s wordy, but it is the common format in a formal context. Your alternatives work well in less formal contexts.   A press conference with your Mr Trump: “I received a phone call today from President Putin.”   Him earlier on Twitter: “President Putin called me today.”

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful. 
Also 'take' 
'If he rings I will take his call' 
'I took a phone call from'
A secretary may ask 'can you take a call from'